# Java opencv - Error - no jniopencv_core in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I'm getting this error when running my Java project I'm using NetBeans 8.0 on Max OS X.

Please help me to fix!

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure, that opencv-macosx-x86_64.jar is in your classpath.